# Why Plugin is not working on ListProduct 's getProductDetailsHtml

Tags: magento2, overrides, plugin, magento2.2.3

I  have tried to create plugin of  method `getProductDetailsHtml` of `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`.

But this plugin is not working.

**di.xml**

```
<type  name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
   <plugin name="changes_template_of_product_list" sortOrder="1"  disabled="false"
   type="StackExchange\Magentodemo\Plugin\Block\ListProductPlugin"/>
</type>
```

**Plugin class**

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Magentodemo\Plugin\Block;

class ListProductPlugin
{

    public function aroundGetProductDetailsHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $result = $proceed($product);
        $result. 'Test';
        return $result. 'Test';
    }

}
```

Now, if I changed the class at di. and plugin class

`Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct` from `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` the then plugin is working perfectly.

**Now Question:**

Why plugin is not working on `ListProduct`  where it is worked on `AbstractProduct`?

If we **do di compile** then will find **that  both class's Interceptor class**
has `getProductDetailsHtml()` method.So **it means that we can create plugin at    getProductDetailsHtml method at both class**.

> Interceptor class  of \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;

/**
 * Interceptor class for @see \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 */
class Interceptor extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct implements \Magento\Framework\Interception\InterceptorInterface
{



    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getProductDetailsHtml');
        if (!$pluginInfo) {
            return parent::getProductDetailsHtml($product);
        } else {
            return $this->___callPlugins('getProductDetailsHtml', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
        }
    }

      /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getImage($product, $imageId, $attributes = array())
    {
        $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getImage');
        if (!$pluginInfo) {
            return parent::getImage($product, $imageId, $attributes);
        } else {
            return $this->___callPlugins('getImage', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
        }
    }

}
```

> Interceptor class of \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;

/**
 * Interceptor class for @see \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
 */
class Interceptor extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct implements \Magento\Framework\Interception\InterceptorInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'getProductDetailsHtml');
        if (!$pluginInfo) {
            return parent::getProductDetailsHtml($product);
        } else {
            return $this->___callPlugins('getProductDetailsHtml', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
        }
    }


}
```

But **really strange that the plugin** is not working on `ListProduct` class. Where it should work.

Also, I am avoiding to create  **plugin** on `AbstractProduct` as this class is deprecated from version 101.1.0.

> **So, anybody has idea Why Plugin is not working on  ListProduct 's  getProductDetailsHtml()**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think of right now: the class `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` is not used, but some other class instead which inherits `AbstractProduct`, maybe via preferences. Could you check?

Comment: Let me cross check..

Comment: Confirm you that list.phtml is render by `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`

Comment: Any idea on this...

Comment: @AmitBera Sorry, no. I tried to get it to work - for me, not even the version with `AbstractProduct` worked :-/